# Handling dynamic background from React state

Tags: reactjs

I have a React component, that has a background image. The choice of an image is handled like this:

```js
state = {
   image: 0
}

let backgroundImage;

    backgroundImage =
      "url(" +
      require(`../../img/bar/${getProgressBackground(this.state.image)}`) +
      ")";
```

There's an action button, that, once triggered, sets a counter to the `image` state:

```js
.then(() => {
  events.watch(
    function(err, result) {
      if (!err && result.event === "Event") {
        this.setState({
          loading: false,
          image: this.state.image + 1,

        });
      } else if (err) {
        alert(
          "An error happened!"
        );
      }
    }.bind(this)
  );
});
```

The expected behavior is that when triggered, the button would `setState` `image` from 0 to 1, and then `getProgressBackground` would pick the proper background and change it as needed.

However, what I receive is an error, and the app is looping and crashing:

```js
Warning: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render` or another component's constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to `componentWillMount`.
```

What would be the right way to handle this and get the expected behavior?

Comment: Can you paste the code where you're using setState?

Comment: Updated in the code.

Comment: How do you use backgroundImage in your page as far as it rendering in the image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use require dynamically like this.

Use a switch instead:

```js
switch (name) {
  case 'a': return require('./a');
  case 'b': return require('./b');
  // etc...
}
```

as suggested in [this issue.](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6391#issuecomment-194581270)

Your code should look something like this:

```js
getProgressBackground = progressState => {
    case 'ready':  return require('/path/to/greenBg.jpg');
    case 'inProgress': return require('path/to/yellowBg.jpg');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I can't understand where do I have to use the switch. Is it in inside of the render?

Comment: I moved everything into a switch case, but it still doesn't work. I get the same loop.

Comment: I completed my answer how it might look like in your case.